# CSS fixed div with float right and left positioning

Tags: html, css, css-float

So I have navbar with float right and 330px left. Everything is working fine with absolute position but I want fixed and here comes the problem. How I'm suposed to do it ? I also tried various of methods but they don't seem to work I really hope that there is some really easy method but I can't figure it out.
Here is my code
HTML

```
<div id="nav" >
    <ul>
        <li><img class="toggle-slide-button" src="assets/images/menu/menutoggle.png" alt=""></li>
        <li><img class="Menu_icon"src="assets/images/menu/Home_icon.png" alt="">
        <div class="menu_text">Home</div>
        <img  class="boxx" src="assets/images/menu/box.png" alt="">

        </li>

    </ul>

</div>
```

CSS

```
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background: url(../images/Home/Screen_1/home_final_background.png) 100% 0 fixed;
}
ul{
    list-style-type:none
}
.Menu_icon{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
#nav{ float: right;  z-index: 152; right: -330px; 

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: initial !important;
    position: fixed;
}
.menu_text{
    color:white;
    font-size:24px;
    height: 132px;
    width: 390px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    z-index: -2;
}
```

JS

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
    var state = true;

    $(".toggle-slide-button").click(function () {
        if (!state) {
            $('#nav').stop().animate({left:330}, 1000);
              state = true;
            }
        else {
              $('#nav').stop().animate({left: 20}, 1000);
              state = false;
            }
    });
    });



 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".boxx").hover(function() {
        $(this).attr("src","assets/images/menu/box_hover.png");
            }, function() {
        $(this).attr("src","assets/images/menu/box.png");
    });
});
```

EDIT: here is what I want to make

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



 <style>
 img{
  user-drag: none; 
-moz-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-drag: none;
 }
 body{
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/z1y0hYN.png) 100% 0 fixed; 
 }
 ul{
  list-style-type:none
 }
 .Menu_icon{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
 }
 #nav{
  float: right;
  left:330px;
  margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
 }
 .menu_text{
  color:white;
  font-size:24px;
  height: 132px;
  width: 390px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  z-index: -2;
 }

 </style>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var state = true;

  $(".toggle-slide-button").click(function () {
      if (!state) {
          $('#nav').stop().animate({left:330}, 1000);
            state = true;
          }
      else {
            $('#nav').stop().animate({left: 20}, 1000);
            state = false;
          }
  });
  });
 </script>



<script  type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".boxx").hover(function() {
  $(this).attr("src","http://i.imgur.com/MlmFvp3.png");
   }, function() {
  $(this).attr("src","http://i.imgur.com/FCKVSFe.png");
 });
});
</script>


















 <div id="nav">
  <ul>
   <li><img class="toggle-slide-button" src="http://i.imgur.com/WsgovYE.png" alt=""></li>
   <li><img class="Menu_icon"src="http://i.imgur.com/rYo7Utj.png" alt="">
   <div class="menu_text">Home</div>
   <img  class="boxx" src="http://i.imgur.com/FCKVSFe.png" alt="">
   
   </li>
   
  </ul>

 </div>
```

Comment: Please provide us a sample image or detailed description of you expected result.

Comment: When fixed you set its position relative to the viewscreen. it will not respond to your layout with a float. So what is it you want to do?

Comment: Can you clarify the question and problem? You said "Everything is working fine" and you need "Fixed" in the the first sentence. Are you trying to animate to a fixed position or an absolute position? (doesn't move in screen or doesn't move in page)

Comment: I edited the post with the desired effect. E.g. I want this effect but with postion: fixed on #nav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `position:fixed` you can position the `#nav` element to the right side of the screen by either adding: `right: 0` or `left: 100%` (not both). Since you only want a small  part of the `#nav` to be visible by default, you can push the element 'out of the screen' by setting a negative margin, for example:

```
#nav {
    position: fixed;
    left: 100%;
    width: 400px;
    margin-right: -300px; /* (400px-300) keeps 100px of the element in sight */
}
```

Here's a working example of your code with `#nav` set to `position:fixed`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var state;

  $(".toggle-slide-button").click(function() {
    if (!state) {
      $('#nav').stop().animate({
        'margin-left': '-330px'
      }, 1000);
      state = true;
    } else {
      $('#nav').stop().animate({
        'margin-left': '-65px'
      }, 1000);
      state = false;
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".boxx").hover(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/MlmFvp3.png");
  }, function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/FCKVSFe.png");
  });
});
```

```css
.just-a-dummie-element {
  height: 2600px;
}
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/z1y0hYN.png) 100% 0 fixed;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.toggle-slide-button {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.Menu_icon {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  left: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 0 -65px;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu_text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  height: 132px;
  width: 390px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="just-a-dummie-element">..just to make the page loger!</div>

<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img class="toggle-slide-button" src="http://i.imgur.com/WsgovYE.png" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="Menu_icon" src="http://i.imgur.com/rYo7Utj.png" alt="" />
      <div class="menu_text">Home</div>
      <img class="boxx" src="http://i.imgur.com/FCKVSFe.png" alt="" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Also, just a simple tip: don't use javascript to change the background of the `.boxx` on `:hover`, just use css.